# WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager)

Tags: java, log4j

My **log4j properties file**

```
log4j.logger.devpinoyLogger=DEBUG, dest1,
log4j.appender.dest1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dest1.maxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.dest1.maxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.dest1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dest1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %m%n
log4j.appender.dest1.File=C:\\Selenium\\eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32\\eclipse\\Workspace\\Core_Hybrid\\src\\com\\logs\\Application.log
log4j.appender.dest1.Append=false
```

I get the **Error msg** as stated below :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I have placed my properties files inside the src folder and imported the log4j.jar in the build path.

Please help on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I remember the `log4j.properties` file must be in the `root-directory` of the execution and added to the classPath. So this means the file must be on the same level as the `src-Folder` and not within this folder. Or you have to change the root-directory of your execution to your src-folder.

Comment: I have tried placing the jar file in the src or classpath folder it didn't work. My logs are generated but I get the warning msg. How do I configure.

Answer (score 3):

There's a typo in your configuration file. Remove the last ',' in the first line:

```
     log4j.logger.devpinoyLogger=DEBUG, dest1
```

You should define a root logger to avoid such "No appender" warning.

```
      log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, dest1
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it will help:

```
org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4j.propertiesLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the add part of your package URL and all sub-packages will be printed to the log:

Here is an example:

log4j.logger.org.apache=DEBUG, stdout

Answer (score 0):

Question :-- log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
ANSWER  you should add below line in main method class its working

PropertyConfigurator.configure("src/main/java/com/nsettle/config/log4j.properties");